# PCB Trace Widths?

Tags: pcb, design

I am designing a circuit board using proteus 8.1 , does anyone know how to calculate trace widths for the PCB tracks , it may need to handle a high current so it’s important this is all calculated , is there a simple calculation to find the width a track needs too be, for example I need to be able to send 12V with up too 9A through part of the PCB, how wide will the PCB trace width need to be ? Any ideas , Thanks

Comment: I would agree with the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I googled "pcb trace width calculator" : https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html

Comment: When I did, my second option was a link directly back to StackExchangeEE

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a simple calculation does not exist, as there are many variables that contribute to the required trace width including trace length, copper thickness, current, temperature rise, etc... IPC-2152 contains dozens of charts and examples. Specifically, figure 5-1 shows the temperature rise for a given conductor width, which can be used to help identify the optimal trace width for your specific application. There are also calculators and plugins for common PCB design software that uses IPC-2152 charts to calculate width for you.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 oz copper on an outer layer, a 275 mil wide trace will have a 10 degree C rise at 9A.
Assuming a standard 0.062" thick board.